# Dart: Issue casting set to list

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello lovely community.
I am trying to include a dropdown menu in my widget, for that I need to prepare a `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>` following this documentation:`https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html`. I am really new to dart. I seem to be too stupid to get it working.

I have the following setup:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> categoriesAsDropdownList() {
  return <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String cat) => {
            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: cat,
              child: Text(cat),
            )
          })
      .toList();
}
```

The issue is as follws:

```
The return type 'Set<DropdownMenuItem<String>>' isn't a 'DropdownMenuItem<String>', as required by the closure's context.
```

I have sat in front of this for a couple of hours now. I assume it's an easy solution, but can't seem to find the issue.

Best of Wishes,
Pascal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redundant {} braces. Rewrite code like this:

```dart
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> categoriesAsDropdownList() {
  return <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String cat) =>
            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: cat,
              child: Text(cat),
            )
          )
      .toList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Quite a bad habit I have brought over.